# Webdings not showing correctly in google chrome after update 52

Tags: html, google-chrome, fonts

i have a webpage that uses webdings extensively to show downward arrow.
Following code demonstrates how it is achieved.

```
<html>
<body>
The webding font below should render to a downward arrow.
<p style="font-family: webdings">6</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But after recently updating chrome, i see the number 6 instead of the expected downward arrow symbol.

*Before update 52 (tested on update 49)*

[image: before update]

*After update 52*

[image: after update]

Webdings is a web safe font hence i believe it must be rendered uniformly across all browsers.

Are there any settings in chrome to get back the required behavior?
Let me know alternate solutions if not.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. Tried the beta of Chrome 53 and its still broken but it appears to be fixed in the Dev version of Chrome 54. Not sure how long it takes for these versions to get released so looks like our site will stay messed up for now.